# diff command for comparing files more than 2GB in solaris?

Tags: solaris, diff

how to run recursively diff command for comparing files of file size more than 2GB in solaris?

Comment: What do you want to do recursively ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Solaris diff is [**largefile**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5175/largefile-5.html#scrolltoc) safe but not largefile aware so it can't handle files >2Gb. Solaris has the [**bdiff**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/bdiff-1.html#scrolltoc) command that may help you.

Comment: You can also just use GNU diff, which is already installed as gdiff on many Solaris systems.

Comment: @alanc: OpenSolaris has gdiff but I don't think Solaris does by default.

Comment: GNU diff does come on the Solaris 10 companion disk.  It's under /opt/sfw/bin/gdiff which may not be in your search path.